# C# help please for "The debugger could not locate the source file" (likely a broken reference/ path issue)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

this afternoon I'm a bit bogged down with trying to run my VS2010 project after moving the solution it's in as well as a couple other projects from the solution. I updated the address strings in the properties window to the new addresses, and of three projects, only one seems to be choking. I get a

- NullReferenceException unhandled exception,

and when I step into it I get

- no source available window,

with the last line in the information given being key:

- "The debugger could not locate the source file 'C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop..."

but the address is the original address, as in before the move, and before I updated the directory string property.

Is there another place I need to update this?

FYI The one that runs is a driver... the one that throws the error is a library of my abstract base classes that the driver project uses.

I thought I'd spare the group from pouring over my abstract base class hierarchies if it's a simple setting that is on the nose obvious. Thanks.

Comment: When you start debugging, check the Output window to see which debug library is being loaded for the chocking project.

Comment: @EddiePaz Thanks. I see a reference to it in debug output, but it's a similar error message to what I've seen, a reference to the project but by the old address, still unsure of how to proceed..

Answer (score 1):

Update the Reference to the Project. You cannot simple just copy over the files.

Comment: Thanks... where/ how though? Under "references" in my working driver, I click the project in question, and it appears to have the correct path.

Comment: Check in the .csproj for the driver project and check what the <HintPath> for the library reference is. Or, you could delete the reference and add it again.

Comment: @EddiePaz Thank you sir, we're good... I removed then readded the reference, pretty simple stuff.

Comment: Don't forget to flag Brad's response as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Had this same issue and re-adding the reference had no effect... however closing the file in VS which is in the other 'Assembly / Module' and then stepping back into the file so it is re-opened solved the issue for me.